# How can I pass a property as a param to Converter and property is outside of list itemsource context xaml - Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, converters

I am working on `Listview`, one of `Label` inside `Cell` using `Converter`, I need to pass one property as `converter` `parameter` which is not part of `itemsource` but defined in `viewmodel`.

This is my code

```
<Label FontSize="10"    
Text="Insufficient Funds"                                              
IsVisible="{Binding balance, Converter={StaticResource IsInsufficientBalanceConverter}, Source={x:Reference Name=multiCardPage}, ConverterParameter={x:Reference BindingContext.Subtotal} }">
```

Getting this exception

```
Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: 'Position 120:52. Can not find the object referenced by BindingContext.Subtotal'
```

**What I want to do :**
I have a value `Subtotal` (not part of itemsource). In itemsource, there is `balance` property, if `balance` is less than `Subtotal`, I want to display above `Insufficient Funds Label` otherwise this `Label` should be invisible. For this I want to pass Subtotal to Converter with balance so that I can get `true` or `false` value.

How can I make it work ?

**Edit 1:** I want `view` and `converter` to listen the changes in `subtotal` value and update the UI accordingly so that `Insufficient balance` `label` can visible/invisible as per balance in `listview`. I have tried multibindings but that is not supporting the case with list/collection. How can I fix this.

Comment: Add one more boolean property to the list's model like "IsInsufficientFund" and bind this value to the visibility converter. Set this "IsInsufficientFund" value and raise property changed event in the following three ways. 1) while creating model list 2) Whenever Subtotal value is getting changed (loop through the bound list and update) 3) Whenever balance value getting changed. Using this way you do not need to reload the page or listview. Raise property changed will take care of updating the UI listview.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I pass a property as a param to Converter and property is
> outside of list itemsource context xaml - Xamarin

You don't need to pass the `Subtotal` as a param to Converter, you can just refer the `Subtotal` in your Converter class.

Please refer to the following code(suppose the type of `Subtotal`   is `int`):

```
public class InsufficientBalanceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    const int Subtotal = 5;
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
         int mValue =  (int)value;

        if (mValue < Subtotal)
        {

            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In the xaml, we can do like this:

```
<Label x:Name="mQuantity" Text="Insufficient Funds"    
       IsVisible="{Binding balance, Converter={StaticResource MyInsufficientBalanceConverter} }" />
```

And the `Resources` in xaml is:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converts:InsufficientBalanceConverter x:Key="MyInsufficientBalanceConverter"></converts:InsufficientBalanceConverter>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

**Update:**

> Subtotal is getting updated every time user removes times from cart,
> in that case converter will have the old subtotal value.

You can define a static global variable for `subtotal`  (instead of a constant) in your other class and refer it in  the `InsufficientBalanceConverter` . In this condition, once the value of `Subtotal` is changed ,  we can get the latest the value of `Subtotal`.

For example:

```
public class Variables
{  // here we can change the value of `Subtotal `as we need.
     public static int Subtotal = 5;
}
```

And we can refer it like this:

```
public class InsufficientBalanceConverter : IValueConverter
{
     //public  static int  Subtotal = 5;
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
         int mValue =  (int)value;

        if (mValue < Variables.Subtotal)
        {

            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems good but here converter is a concrete .cs class so getting viewmodel data will be not be easy. Is there other way around.

Comment: Subtotal is getting updated every time user removes times from cart, in that case converter will have the old subtotal value.

Comment: ` in that case converter will have the old subtotal value. `  You can define a static global variable for `subtotal ` .I have updated the answer,you can check it.

Comment: thank you. One more thing here subtotal will be change but converter wont be hitting in this case. How can I let view know there is some change in subtotal, so that converter  can hit and I will get latest true false values.

Comment: Once the value of `subtotal` being changed, you can refresh and reload the page.

Comment: this seems good but my is payment page so loading the page will not be good idea, I am looking for some kind of multibinding so that view recognize the subtotal property changes and hit the converter.

Comment: What's special about the Payment page?Once the value of `subtotal` being changed,  you can notice(e.g. send message to the Payment page)   Payment page to refresh the UI.

Comment: This page has list of payment methods(credit card, Visa, wallet etc. and Textbox at right side to enter amount), I can enter split amount against each paymentMethods. If subtotal is $10.00, paymentMethod1(balance $8.00, will show insufficient balance label). Once I enter $5.00 against paymentMethod2, subtotal will be $5.00, Now from paymentMethod1 Insufficient balance label should disappear. I will try to add UI screenshot for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

This is an addition to [Jessie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70445752/199364).

You can use MessagingCenter to tell the page the new subtotal.

In this example, properties are bound to the page. If using MVVM, some of the code will instead be in the VM.

PaymentPage.xaml:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Subtotal}" />
```

PaymentPage.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class PaymentPage : ContentPage
{
    public PaymentPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    public int Subtotal
    {
        get => _subtotal;
        set
        {
            _subtotal = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private int _subtotal;


    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<PaymentCalc, int>(this, "NewSubTotal", (sender, value) =>
        {
            Subtotal = value;
        });
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<PaymentCalc, int>(this, "NewSubTotal");
    }
}
```

In order to use MessagingCenter, there needs to be some class that will send the message. Here, I define `PaymentCalc`.

PaymentCalc.cs:

```
class PaymentCalc
{
    public void NewSubTotal(int value)
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send(this, "NewSubTotal", value);
    }
}
```

Now anywhere in code, do this, to calculate a new Subtotal, and send it to PaymentPage:

```
var it = new PaymentCalc();
it.NewSubTotal(12345);
```

If you already have a class in which you are doing this calculation, then simply add NewSubTotal to it, or put that Send message in some appropriate method. You'll need to change PaymentPage's Subscribe and Unsubscribe to use the name of your class, instead of PaymentCalc.